# Pass argument to Meta class of Django Modelform

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have models that have common fields like this:

```
class Model_1(models.Model):
    field_1 
    field_2
    field_3
    # Other fields
class Model_2(models.Model):
    field_1 
    field_2
    field_3
    # Other fields
```

Then I want to create one form for both of them like this:

```
class CommonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         variable_of_name_of_model = that pass to Meta class
         # this condition check for 
         if  variable_of_name_of_model == 'Model_1':
             model = Model_1
         elif variable_of_name_of_model == 'Model_2':
             model = Model_2
         fields = ['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3']
```

In this form, I check the `variable_of_name_of_model` that has been passed to the `Meta` class 
and do something after that.

***How can I do that? In other hand, how can I pass argument to `Meta` class?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use kind of fabrik method:

```
def get_form_class(model_name,data, instance):
    class CommonForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = model_name
            fields = ['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3']
        form = CommonForm(data=data, instance=instance)
        return form
```

Just call it with model name in place where you'd like to use it (views?). Something like this:

```
form = get_form_class(model_name=ModelName, data=request.POST, instance=instance,)
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I pass `request.POST, instance=instance,` to my form? @charnel

Comment: Same way as with any other form or like this `form = get_form_class(model_name)(request.POST, instance=instance)`

Comment: It doesn't works! I think that we need to pass our `request.POST` and `instance` to our function and then get them in class like this: `    form = CommonForm(data=data, instance=instance)
    return form` @charnel

Comment: Yes, you can pass thous attrs to function, but I wonder what error it raises now?

Comment: This is message box: `Thanks for submitting an edit. It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members` . So thank you. I accept your answer.  @charnel

Comment: Ah, I though you where talking about code in a question. Glad to help!